# How do I make a duplicate of a folder on a remote server with asp.net and keep it speedy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, io

I have an ASP.NET page that needs to make a duplicate of a folder that resides on another server.   ***All*** of the file IO runs on the remote server.  This is **not** a question about how to copy files from one computer to another, nor is it a question about how to do a recursive directory copy.  Those tasks are pretty easy.

What I've found is that making a copy of a directory on the server running the ASP.NET application is nice and fast.  As soon as the source and destination folder reside on a remote server (i.e. a file server), it becomes **incredibly slow**.  I can't figure out why it's so slow, which means I can't really figure out a good way to get around the problem.  To be perfectly clear, here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

- The asp.net application is running on a server named "webserver"
- The files are located on a server named "fileserver"
- I need the website running on "webserver" to make a recursive duplicate of \\fileserver\files\setup named \\fileserver\files\setup_temp

If there are already answers to this question then please point me in the right direction.  I found loads of answers to the "how do I make a recursive copy" and "how do I copy a folder to another server"

Comment: How slow is "incredible slow"?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using some remote execution commands instead of doing that from the web app itself. For e.g., using [Powershell](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_invoke.htm) or [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) that will not require your web app to keep a connection for the two end points of the copy operation. I am not sure how you are doing the copy but if you are calling anything in .NET to do that work, that means your server is a middle man for that operation and that will slow it down.

When I re-read your message, it looks like you are thinking the IO happens on the remote server itself. In which case, these suggestions might not be of much use. :(

Answer (score 0):

How does the Webserver communicate with the Fileserver? The transfer of data between those two is definitely your bottleneck. I would recommend using a WCF service to transfer one file/folder at a time (depending on the size of the data). If the files are really large i would also recommend enabling [streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx).